# Ember app kit - Extend super Route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, naming-conventions, ember-app-kit

Hi I want extend my super route class something like this :

```
//routes/auth.js
export default Em.Route.extend({
  someFunction:function(){
     //code
  }
});

//routes/test.js
export default App.AuthRoute.extend({
  model: function(){
     return this.someFunction(); //Call function from super class
  }
});
```

routes/test.js doesnt work -white screen and nothing in console - I do not know naming conventions to get this.

Comment: I'm finding your question a bit too vague to really comment on.  Can you go into more detail about what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @gravityplanx I have edit the question, I need some super Class Route to inherit from. I want create new routes with same functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import any other modules that you reference first so that they can be resolved:

```
import AuthRoute from 'appkit/routes/auth';

export default AuthRoute.extend({
   ....
});
```